# Sonar "Make this member "protected"

Tags: java, java-11

I have a constant clsss. inside constant class one "public final static" map. below code

```
public static final Map<String, String> TYPES = Stream.of(new String[][]{
            {"T1", "ABC"},
            {"T2", "ABC1"},
            {"T3", "ABC2"},
            {"T4", "ABC3"},
            {"T4", "ABC4"}
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> data[0], data -> data[1]));
```

In the above method sonar showing "Make this member "protected" if I make this as protected I got compilation error.
Can sone one help me on this? to refactor this  I am using java 11

Comment: Why not use [`Map.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V))?

Comment: Thanks for advice. But not understand could you please explain more? where I have to use

Comment: `Map<String, String> TYPES = Map.of("T1", "ABC", "T2", "ABC1", ...)`

Comment: Thanks. If I add "public static final" again it will through same warning:-  public static final Map<String, String> TYPES = Map.of("T1", "ABC", "T2", "ABC1", ...).

Comment: The tool offers advice. The advice does not work. Ignore the tool?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @shmosel
Below solution is working..
Map<String, String> TYPES = Map.of("T1", "ABC", "T2", "ABC1", ...)

Comment: needs edits to make answer readable